# display table in gridview for website in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, ms-access

I am new to vb.net and I want to display an Access table in gridview using vb.net in an ASP.NET secnario.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        BindGrid()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindGrid()
        Dim constring As String = "Data Source=.\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User id = sa;password=pass@123"
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is something not working, or...?

Comment: Your `constring` looks incorrect, at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

To use a ACCESS database you must change your connection string.

```
Dim constring As String = "Data Source=.\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User id = sa;password=pass@123"
```

To

```
    http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/
```

Also

```
                Using ds As New DataSet()
                    sda.Fill(ds)
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Table(0)
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
```